# ambiguous reference to evaluate()

Tags: swift, function, return, ambiguous

I'm building a calculator and when I put return evaluate() inside the function performOperation I get error ambiguous reference to evaluate.
here is the function and the func I called:

```
 func evaluate() -> Double? { let (result, _) = evaluate(opStack)
    return result
}
 func performOperation(symbol: String) {
        if let operation = knownOps[symbol] {
            opStack.append(operation)
        }
       return evaluate()
    }
```

Comment: is there more to this code?  I see you trying to returning something from `performOperation`, even though you don't declare a return value for that function.  Also, you declare `evaluate()` as a function that takes no parameters, but then there's an `evaluate(opStack)` call inside it (where `opStack` is a parameter).

Comment: ya, there is, but I fixed it. It was cuz I didn't have a return value for the function

Comment: oh, so everything is okay and you don't have a question anymore?

Comment: ya. Thank you.  :)